# how to find $f(2)$

Tags: calculus

Hello im trying to solve a homework problem and i'm stumped.
here is the problem.

the question states
suppose $f$ and $g$ are continuous functions such that $g(2)=6$
and 
$\lim_{x\to 2}$
 $[3f(x)+f(x)g(x)]=36$ find $f(2)$

i have tried solving it by doing the following but i get the wrong answer.

3$f(2)$+$f(2)$g(2)=36 
    3$f(2)$ +$f$(2)6=36
 
    $f(2)$+$f(2)$= 36-18
     $f(2)$ +$f(2)$ = 16

how do i finish the problem? the answer is 4 but i dont see how to get there now?
Thanks for any help in advance.
Thanks
Miguel

[actual problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvZCb.png)

Comment: What happened on the third line?  Then what happened on the fourth line?

Comment: i took the 3 from the far left and i multiply times 6  to get 18 and subtract from the other side.

Comment: Typically $ab+bc\neq ab+b+ac$, but rather, $ab+bc=(a+c)b$.  For example, $3\times 12 +12\times 6 \neq 3\times 12 + 12 +18$, but rather, $3\times 12+12\times 6 =9\times 12$.

Comment: The recent edit replaced one error with another, implying that $36-18=16$.

Comment: Jonas thank you this is a very silly mistake on my part i totally see my error now. thank you and i appreciate your respond.

Comment: You're welcome.  I appreciate your question because of its clarity and explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got it all right up until the third line,

$3f(2)+f(2)g(2)=36$

$3f(2) +f(2)6=36$

$3f(2)+f(2)= 36-18$ <- not sure what you are doing here, but it doesn't look right

Anyway, continuing from the second line,

$3f(2) +f(2)6=36$

$f(2)(3+6)=36$

$f(2) = 36/9 = 4$

Comment: thats where i get confused... i have 2f(2) so how do i end up with f(2)(3+6)=36?

Comment: sorry, what did you mean by 2f(2)? After, 3f(2)+6f(2)=36, all I did was to factor out f(2), which gives f(2)(3+6) = 36

Comment: ahhhhh !!!! factor thats where im going wrong. im such an idiot. thank you .

Comment: Thank you for the response. i get it now.

Answer (score 1):

From
$$3f(2)+f(2)6=36,$$
we have $$9f(2)=36 \Rightarrow f(2)=4$$

Comment: what happens two the second f(2)? thats where im stumped. how can you end up with 9f(2)=36 when their are two 2f(2)'s?

Comment: @Miguel: The distributive property of multiplication and addition says that $ab + ac = a(b+c)$.  For example, $3\times 4+3\times 26 = 3\times (4+26)$, $6x+82x = 88x$, $3f(2)+f(2)6=3f(2)+6f(2)=9f(2)$, etc.  Or if you prefer, "factor out" $f(2)$.

Comment: It means that $f(2)$ is multiplied by $g(2)=6$:
 $$f(2)g(2)=f(2)\cdot6=6\cdot f(2).$$ Next by collecting terms $3f(2)$ and $6f(2)$ we have $3f(2)+6f(2)=(3+6)f(2)=9f(2)$

Comment: $3f(2) +f(2)6=36$ means finding the value of function at 2 and then multiplying that value by 3, same way finding the value of function at 2 and then multiplying that value by 6 and then add both to get 36, so you have finding the value of function at 2 and then multiplying that value by $(3+6)$